# LaTeX table not compiling/taking a very long time

Tags: tables

I am trying to compile this table and it won't finish. It just keeps on compiling, no erroes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Multiplikation}\\
    Når man multiplicere med binære tal før man det på præcis samme måde som med 10-talssystemet. Man kan altså derfor bruge samme metode som med decimaltallene, se Tabel \ref{tab:multiplikationbiner}. 
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llllllllll|lll}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & $\cdot$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 & $\cdot$ & 6 \\ \hline
      &   &   &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 &   &   & 2 & 4 \\
      &   &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & x &   & 1 & 2 & x \\
      &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 0 & x & x &   &   &   &   \\
      &   & {\footnotesize 1} &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
      & {\footnotesize 1} &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
      &   &   & 1 & 1 & 0 & x & x & x &   &   &   &   \\
      &   & 1 & 1 & 0 & x & x & x & x &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
      & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   & 1 & 4 & 4
      \caption{Multiplikation med binære tal}
    \label{tab:multiplikationbiner}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    Ved at bruge regnereglerne for addition med binære tal kan man lægge tallene sammen i tabellen og finde det endelige resultat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In order to make your code compilable, place the `\caption` and `\lable` outpide of the `tabular` environment, but inside of `table`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did that to all my other tables except this one, i forgot.